# connect a button in xib created Cell to a view in a Tabbed View Application

Tags: uitableview

I In a tabbed application I have a tableView with a custom cell, nibNameOfTblCell, created as a xib file.

It is programmatically linked to the FirstViewController

```
let nib = UINib(nibName: "nibNameOfTblCell", bundle: nil)
tableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

The data in the cells loads in the first view without problem.
However, the xib item is not on the storyboard.  How do I connect the edit button so the user is taken to the SecondViewController.

```
 @IBOutlet weak var memo: UILabel!


    @IBAction func edit(sender: AnyObject) {

        print("Touched Edit button ")
        print(" \(memo.text)")

    //what goes here to send this to the SecondViewController

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I replaced @IBAction edit with edit as an UIButton outlet

```
@IBOutlet weak var edit: UIButton!
```

and in my First ViewController added

```
@IBAction func editCell(sender: UIButton ){

      //did what I needed
}
```

and in tableView set the cell to react on the edit and call the editCell func

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell     {

  cell.edit.addTarget(self, action: "editCell:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```